# RTMP directly to Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, amazon-cloudfront, rtmp, live-streaming

*this is what i have:*

Teradek Vidiu, sending 1 fullhd RTMP stream in port 1935

**what i want to achieve:**
i don`t want to use a transcoder server (i'm using a transcoder server right now but don't want it anymore), i want to stream to cloudfront directly and use it's "smooth streaming" technology.

i don't now how to do this, i have read a lot but nothing comes close to what i want, the stream is already transcoded, so, i don't have to use a server.
Any suggestions? alternatives? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing some terms here, so let me clarify:

**Transcoding** is the act of taking media encoded in a specific way, and re-encoding it another way. For example going from MPEG2 to H.264, or from WAV to MP3.

A **server** makes data available somehow, regardless of transcoding.

With that in mind, it sounds like you want to go from an RTMP source stream to an HSS target. These two protocols are not directly compatible, and you'll have to demux the RTMP stream and mux it as HSS.
You'll need to use *something* to do this, and one of the options is your current transcoding server solution.

An alternative would be using a tool like ffmpeg to to the trans-muxing for you, without re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://source/url/here -c copy http://target/url/here.ism
```

Do note that this requires the RTMP stream to be available somewhere already. If you need to receive a stream, you'll need to listen for incoming RTMP connections and handle it accordingly. An easy way to solve that is to use any RTMP-compatible media server software to receive the stream, and then either use ffmpeg as above or if the software already supports it use the software directly to stream out to HSS.